# What is the difference between "task" and "assignment"?

Tags: differences, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Task, project, assignment, job. Which one is correct in my case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58307/task-project-assignment-job-which-one-is-correct-in-my-case)

These words don't have exact matches in Portuguese, so sometimes I get confused about their usage. When is it more suitable to use *task* rather than *assigment* and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

Task is a piece of work to be done or undertaken.

Assignment is a task assigned as part of a job or course of study.

In short, assignment = task given to you.